# nodejs express nested sequelize async await

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, nested, sequelize.js

I could not get the a nested logic to work. I need to combined data from 2 table and return it to the request. I do not want a join table as I need to return an individual record from tableA first then combine with tableB record before it is returned. Below is my simplified code

```
exports.get_caution_reasons = async (req, res) => {
   let return_data = [];
   await db.sequelize.query("SELECT TableA xxxxx",{
                type: QueryTypes.SELECT
            }).then(recordA => {
                for (let index = 0; index < recordA.length; index++) {
                    return_data.push({recordA[index].xxx, recordA[index].yyy})
                    db.sequelize.query("SELECT TableB xxxxx WHERE zzz=recordA.zzz",{
                       type: QueryTypes.SELECT
                    }).then(recordB => {
                        for (let index = 0; index < recordB.length; index++) {
                            return_data.push({recordB[index].xxx, recordB[index].yyy}) 
                        }   
                    })
                }
                res.status(200).json({data: return_data});
            })
};
```

It only return the record for TableA only. I tried various async and await to get the recordB in there but without success. Any help is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like that should work:

```
exports.get_caution_reasons = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        let options = { type: QueryTypes.SELECT }
        let data = []
        let result_a = await db.sequelize.query("SELECT TableA xxxxx", options)
        for (let index = 0; index < result_a.length; index++) {
            data.push({ /* whatever you need... */ })
            let result_b = await db.sequelize.query("SELECT TableB xxxxx WHERE zzz=recordA.zzz", options)
            for (let index = 0; index < result_b.length; index++) {
                data.push({ /* ... */ })
            }
        }
        res.json({ data })
    } catch (err) {
        next(err)
    }
}
```